# How to create a PyTorch hook with conditions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I'm learning about hooks and working with binarized neural network. The issue is that sometimes my gradients are 0 in the backwards pass. I'm trying to replace those gradients with a certain value.

Say I have the following network

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)        
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
```

And also some features

```
features = torch.rand((3,1))
```

I can train it normally using:

```
for i in range(10):
    opt.zero_grad()
    out = net(features)
    loss = torch.mean(torch.square(torch.tensor(5) - torch.sum(out)))
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
```

How can I attach a hook function that will have the following conditions for the backwards pass (for each layer):

- If all the gradients in a single layer are 0, change them to 1.0.
- If one of the gradients is 0 but the there's at least one gradient that is not 0, change it to 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a callback function on your `nn.Module` with [`nn.Module.register_full_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_full_backward_hook#torch.nn.Module.register_full_backward_hook):

You will have to handle both cases: if all elements are equal to zero using [`torch.all`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.all.html), else (*i.e.* at least one is non zero) if at least one is equal to zero using [`torch.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.any.html).

```
def grad_mod(module, grad_inputs, grad_outputs):
    if module.weight.grad is None: # safety measure for last layer 
        return None                # and layers w/ require_grad=False

    flat = module.weight.grad.view(-1)
    if torch.all(flat == 0):
        flat.data.fill_(1.)
    elif torch.any(flat == 0):
        flat.data.scatter_(0, (flat == 0).nonzero()[:,0], value=.5)
```

The instruction in the first clause will fill all values to `1.` while the instruction in the second will only replace zero values with `.5`.

Attach the hook on an `nn.Module`:

```
>>> net.fc3.register_full_backward_hook(grad_mod)
```

Here I use `print` statements before and after mutating `flat` to showcase the effect of the hook:

```
>>> net(torch.rand((3,1))).backward(torch.tensor([[0],[1],[2]]))
>>> tensor([0.0947, 0.0000, 0.0000]) # before
>>> tensor([0.0947, 0.5000, 0.5000]) # after

>>> net(torch.rand((3,1))).backward(torch.tensor([[0],[1],[2]]))
>>> tensor([0., 0., 0.])             # before
>>> tensor([1., 1., 1.])             # after
```

---

In order to apply this hook to multiple layers you can wrap `grad_mod` and utilize [`nn.Module.apply`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.apply) recursive behavior:

```
>>> def apply_grad_mod(module):
...     if hasattr(module, 'weight'):
...         module.register_full_backward_hook(grad_mod)
```

Then the following will apply the hook on all layer weights.

```
>>> net.apply(apply_grad_mod)
```

Note: you will have to extend this behavior if you wish to also affect the biases!